# Best way to include Bootstrap in Wordpress

Tags: themes, twitter-bootstrap

I am coming from a Laravel background and using Bootstrap in Laravel is relatively easy. However I have a project I have been working on with Wordpress and I am using Bootstrap for my nav bars. The problem is that, they are messing up my header on the page. The theme I am using is Be Theme. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="tabbable">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#link" role="tab" style="color:black;"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#link" role="tab" style="color: black; "></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#link" role="tab" style="color: black;"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#link" role="tab" style="color: black;"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#link" role="tab" style="color: black;"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#link" role="tab" style="color: black;"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#link" role="tab" style="color:black;"></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="link" role="tabpanel" style="; color: black;">  


    <form action="" method="get" name="" style="color: black;" class="form-inline">
    <br>

    <br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: red;">
</form>

<table>

</table>




    </div>
  <div class="tab-pane " id="id" role="tabpanel" style=";">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane " id="id" role="tabpanel" style=";">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane " id="id" role="tabpanel" style=";">
  </div>

   <div class="tab-pane " id="id" role="tabpanel" style=";">
  </div>
   <div class="tab-pane " id="id" role="tabpanel" style=";">
  </div>
   <div class="tab-pane " id="id" role="tabpanel" style=";">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a template page using this code thanks to the help I got in [previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282267/routing-a-custom-php-on-wordpress).

How do I use bootstrap without messing up WP themes and their headers?

EDIT: this is how my functions.php looks like

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mfnch_enqueue_styles', 101 );
function mfnch_enqueue_styles() {

    // Enqueue the parent stylesheet
//  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css' );     //we don't need this if it's empty

    // Enqueue the parent rtl stylesheet
    if ( is_rtl() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'mfn-rtl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css' );
    }

    // Enqueue the child stylesheet
    wp_dequeue_style( 'style' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css' );

}
```

How do I edit this function to include Bootstrap ^? I tried on my own but it doesn't render it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to enqueue scripts and styles in wordpress. I would recommend creating a custom/child theme for your purpose.
This could help you

 custom_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap',  'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add bootstrap in WordPress by following function in functions.php

You can change url as you need if you have cdn.

```
<?php 
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function your_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    // all styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array(), 20141119 );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), 20141119 );
    // all scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '20120206', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Do I need to add this to functions.php of the theme or the child theme?

Comment: You can add in child theme if you have.

Comment: Added my functions.php style function in the OP (without Bootstrap)

Comment: I have realized that it's this script that messes up my header
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: You should add `//` before link.

Comment: like this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js ?

Comment: by // do you mean https:// ?

Comment: // will identify automatic page is coming from secure or non-secure webpage. i.e. http and https
If we write direct : HTTP or HTTPS then will create Parser-blocking, cross site.

Comment: What is the best practice for linking bootstrap from the web (I didn't downloaded it)? How can you add the properties: 'integrity' and 'crossorigin'?

Comment: If you want the library's styles loaded before all other styles, and the theme's styles loaded after all others (with plugin's styles in the middle), you have to use two functions. The first one, with priority "9", will be used to load the library's styles, and the second one, with priority "10", will be used to load the theme's files. Using only one function to load everything, in a theme, results in a situation where the plugin's styles are the first ones to be loaded.

Answer (score 3):

How about to save a bandwidth and possibly increase a page loading speed using MaxCDN and NetDNA.
Add this two functions to your functions.php

```
function pwwp_enqueue_my_scripts() {
    // jQuery is stated as a dependancy of bootstrap-js - it will be loaded by WordPress before the BS scripts 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true); // all the bootstrap javascript goodness
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pwwp_enqueue_my_scripts');

function pwwp_enqueue_my_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

    // this will add the stylesheet from it's default theme location if your theme doesn't already
    //wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pwwp_enqueue_my_styles');
```

[Source docs](https://www.pattonwebz.com/questions/how-to-load-bootstrap-files-from-cdn/)