# Why do all links on my Wordpress site show me the homepage?

Tags: homepage

If my code like this:
[image]

it will show the correct page... But if my code like below it doesn't not work. When I click on any link on my WordPress site it loads homepage, but link URL changes on the address bar. What could be wrong and how can I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've constructed an URL relative to the template PHP you're rendering, i.e.

- this code is in wp-content/themes/mycustom/index.php
- you want to load wp-content/themes/mycustom/admin/dashboard.php
- => relative URL is admin/dashboard.php?

That's not correct. URLs are relative to the URL the user is currently on in their browser, which may be /, or /category/post-slug, or /year/month/post-slug, or many more combinations for the same post. The user never knows they're on template mycustom/index.php. It's safest to use absolute URLs throughout WordPress for this reason, or relative to the root of the domain at the very least. In this case you probably want

```php
get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/dashboard.php'
```

(or get_stylesheet_directory_uri() depending on how you want this to behave for child themes). Possibly run through [esc_js()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_js/) too since you're emitting this into a JavaScript string, although URLs ought to be save without extra escaping in general especially since you control it.

Why the homepage? I'm guessing that's what you've got set up for 404s.

Comment: Note that it isn't very WordPress to load a separate PHP directly rather than through the normal routing mechanism. I don't know what the best solution for that is, but you could e.g. make an empty page on the URL you want and set that up to use a template that includes either admin/dashboard or user/dashboard as appropriate. There are probably also ways to plug this into routing directly without an empty page.

Comment: Old question about routing like this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/282267